# What is the command to check what version of Java ME I have installed?

Tags: debian, java, command

I have Debian 6 installed on a device and want to check what version of Java ME I have installed.

I tried `java -version`, but I get `-sh: java: not found`.

What command should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvm -version`

It produces the same output as `cvm -showversion`

Comment: Googling pretty much only led me to the `java` command. I guess I'll leave the question here in case someone has the same very basic problem as I had.